# How can we add environment parameters to Webview2 under WinUI3?

Tags: c#, webview2, winui-3

I am trying to disable-web-security for WebView2 Runtime but there is no way to overload the EnsureCoreWebView2Async() function.

Any way we can add "--disable-web-security" to the webview2 runtime under WinUI3?

```
{
    CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions environmentOptions = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions() {
        AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--disable-web-security"
    };
    CoreWebView2Environment environment = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateWithOptionsAsync("","", environmentOptions);
    await MyWebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(environment); #This shows error
    MyWebView.Source = new Uri(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Html\mockup.html"));
    MyWebView.CoreWebView2.PermissionRequested += CoreWebView2_PermissionRequested;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this with WinUI3's WebView2 control.

The WinUI3 WebView2 control does not currently support initializing with a custom CoreWebView2Environment. The CoreWebView2Environment would be the only way to pass in a command line parameter like you are trying to do.

You may open a request to change this on the [WinUI3 GitHub project](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20corewebview2environment).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I checked the documentation also, there is no way to initialise in WinUI3 at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can set additional arguments by setting an environment variable before webview2 creation.
`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS", "--disable-web-security");`

Comment: Does this support WinUI 3?

Comment: My mistake, apparently you can't set disable-web-security through an environment variable. Other browser arguments are supported though (also in WinUI 3)

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm looking forward to finding a way to set the proxy ("--proxy-server") in webview2 for WinUI 3. I'll try this out