# Usage ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions in C++Builder 11

Tags: c++builder, webview2, tedgebrowser

I am trying to disable CORS in TEdgeBrowser and found a lot of solutions by using `ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions` because TEdgeBrowser is implement by WebView2.

In [Microsoft's document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2environmentoptions?view=webview2-1.0.1072.54), the sample code seems to used for Visual C++ and C++ Builder is not applicable:

```
auto options = Microsoft::WRL::Make<CoreWebView2ExperimentalEnvironmentOptions>();
```

Here is the code I have tried in C++ Builder 11:

```
_di_ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions *m_WV2_EnvOpt = new _di_ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions();
m_WV2EnvOpt->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(L"--disable-web-security");
```

It would fail in `m_WV2EnvOpt->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments()`.

I have no idea and maybe I got the wrong way. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_di_ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions` is a typedef for [`DelphiInterface`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DelphiInterface) holding a `ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions*` pointer. You don't use `new` on `DelphiInterface` itself, you `new` a class that implements the interface, eg:

```cpp
class TCoreWebView2EnvironmentOptionsImpl : public ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions
{
    // implement IUnknown and ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions as needed...
};

_di_ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions m_WV2_EnvOpt = new TCoreWebView2EnvironmentOptionsImpl;
```

However, WRL objects are not used this way.

In this case, the WebView2 library exposes `ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions` as a COM object, so you can use [`CoCreateInstance()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance) to instantiate it (the `CLSID` for the WebView2 library is `26D34152-879F-4065-BEA2-3DAA2CFADFB8`, and the `IID` for `ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions` is `2FDE08A8-1E9A-4766-8C05-95A9CEB9D1C5`), eg:

```cpp
_di_ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions m_WV2_EnvOpt;
CoCreateInstance(LIBID_WebView2, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions, (LPVOID*)&m_WV2_EnvOpt);
```

However, that doesn't help you in this situation, because you would have to provide the created `ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions` object when creating the WebView2 object, and AFAIK `TEdgeBrowser` simply does not allow you to do that.

You could try setting the `WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS` environment variable before the WebView2 object is created, but AFAIK [this method does not support the `--disable-web-security` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70275952/65863).

Comment: How can I use `WEBVIEW2_ADDITIONAL_BROWSER_ARGUMENTS`? I can't find any properties or methods can set this in TEdgeBrowser.

Comment: @willylu I said it is an "environment variable", so use [`SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setenvironmentvariable)